Making a tally of all visits made by users per date
I'd like to create a tally of all visits made by users per date. Currently I am struggling to find where I will insert the code for computing the tally of each date. Below is my current php code:
$lastvis = '';
$lastui = '';
$count = array();
$i = 0;
    
$tvQuery = "SELECT * FROM visits ORDER BY lastvisit ASC";
$tvQ = $conn->prepare($tvQuery);
$tvQ->execute();
$tvQres = $tvQ->get_result();
while ($row = $tvQres->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row['lastvisit'] == $lastvis) {
        $count[$i]=+1;
    } else {
        $lastvis = $row['lastvisit'];
        echo $i.'<br>';
        $count[$i]=+1;
        echo $count[$i].'<br>';
        $i++;
        echo $lastvis.'<br>';
    }
}

I am echo-ing outputs for verifying whether the values are correct. Here is also the table for the dates: 
So far, I am able to isolate unique dates from the table using the code above. I am trying to input the count of unique users per date in the count array. If you are asking why I am writing this code, I am planning on transferring this data to a graph.

$count[$i]=+1 is equivalent to $count[$i]=1, I assume you want $count[$i]+=1 or $count[$i]++.

I see, I misused the operator. Thanks, that explains why the value I kept on getting didn't change when the conditions were met.

I don't see you are dealing with UIDs anywhere in your code. You're just calculating unique dates, but not unique users-per-date. In any case, you should let the query handle it for you, instead of wasting time looping over the values.
Instead of querying:
$tvQuery = "SELECT * FROM visits ORDER BY lastvisit ASC";

Try:
$tvQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT lastvisit, COUNT(lastvisit) AS numvisits FROM visits GROUP BY lastvisit ASC";

This will return a list of unique dates in the field lastvisit, having a second field numvisits with the number of occurrences of this date in the table.
But if, as I suspect, what you want is a list of unique users-per-date, and assuming the field with the user-id is uid, then the query should be as so:
$tvQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT lastvisit, uid, COUNT(lastvisit) AS numvisits FROM visits GROUP BY lastvisit, uid ASC";

What you are telling the query here is:

order the table, first by date (lastvisit), then by user (uid)
group identical rows (with identical date and user)
count grouped rows
eliminate duplicate rows

So, adapting your original code, it would be like this:
$i = 0;
$tvQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT lastvisit, uid, COUNT(lastvisit) AS numvisits FROM visits GROUP BY lastvisit, uid ASC";
$tvQ = $conn->prepare($tvQuery);
$tvQ->execute();
$tvQres = $tvQ->get_result();
while ($row = $tvQres->fetch_assoc()) {
    $i++;
    echo "$i<br>{$row['numvisits']}<br>{$row['lastvisit']}<br>";
    // Or, if you want UIDs listed as well:
    echo "$i<br>{$row['numvisits']}<br>{$row['uid']}<br>{$row['lastvisit']}<br>";
}

Hope this helps.

Now that you mention it, my current table records unique uid entries and enters the dates of their visit. That's why I sorted it ASC and have a condition for "if the next date is the same".

This helped a lot, thanks! I used the query you made in place of my previous $tvQuery. and used array_push to insert it into the php graphs provided by canvasjs.
